# PHP GD Move Picture Up 1 Px

Tags: php, image, gd, move, pixel

I need to take an image and move it upwards 1 px in certain situations for my code, but with what GD function would I use to do that? I couldn't find another question that asked this, so I asked it. But the middle of the picture is a number and the background is transparent, and the height and width is almost always different

Comment: Can you explain a little about your situation/what you're trying to accomplish? I don't think using a graphics library such as GD would be the best solution for moving an image one pixel.

Comment: Do you possibly mean *cropping 1px off the top of an image*? (hint hint, keyword keyword, google google)

Comment: Cropping is avery good idea, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. The key part is `imagecopymerge()` function. play with it's 0,0,1,0 values.

```
<?php 
$src = imagecreatefromgif($img);
list($w,$h) = getimagesize($img);
$sprite = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);  
$trans = imagecolortransparent($sprite);
imagealphablending($sprite, false);
imagesavealpha($sprite, true);
imagepalettecopy($sprite,$src);                 
imagefill($sprite,0,0,imagecolortransparent($src));
imagecolortransparent($sprite,imagecolortransparent($src));                     
imagecopy($sprite,$src,0,0,1,0,$w,$h);      
imagegif($sprite,$img);
imagedestroy($sprite);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```